# Lock only if same object is passed as a parameter in method

Tags: java, java-8, locking

How can I implement a lock-in java8 when multiple threads try to access the fetchStudentList method?

The condition is like

If the StudentFilter equal object is passed based apply a lock, (one thread at a time in this case)

at the same time allow the other StudentFilter objects to pass-through

```
private List<Students> fetchStudentList(StudentFilter filter) {

  // if same filter object add lock
  // other filter objects can pass through

}


class StudentFilter {

 private final Set<String> divSets;

 public SmscFilter(Set<String> divSets) {
        this.divSets = divSets != null ? divSets : new HashSet<>();
    }

 // getters
 // equals and hashcode 
}
```

Comment: `synchronized(filter) { … … … }`

Answer (score 2):

It may be down to language, but if by "the same StudentFilter object" you mean the exact same instance (i.e., identity), you can synchronize on it. This way, only one call can operate on the same filter at once:

```java
private List<Students> fetchStudentList(StudentFilter filter) {
    synchronized(filter) {
        // logic
    }
}
```

If by "the same StudentFilter" you mean an **equal** object, it would be a bit trickier, but the idea should be similar. One way to implement this is by using a map from the filter (assuming it implements `equals(Object)` and `hashCode()`) to a Lock object:

```java
ConcurrentMap<StudentFilter, Lock> locks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private List<Students> fetchStudentList(StudentFilter filter) {
    Lock lock = locks.computeIfAbsent(filter, f -> new ReentrantLock());
    try {
        lock.lock();
        // logic
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: It’s `->`, not `=>`. Furher, when you use a `ConcurrentHashMap` anyway, you can do it as simple as `locks.computeIfAbsent(filter, f -> { /* logic */ return null; });`

Comment: @Holger been away from Java for too long - good catch, thanks!